# Present perfect simple with "currently"

Tags: present-perfect

Is it correct to say:

"I have worked at Microsoft, Apple and **currently** Google"

meaning you've recently worked in the first two companies, and now in the third one?

Other examples:

"I have been a student in Paris, Rome, Madrid and currently London"
"I have written poetry, fiction and currently newspaper articles"

Answer (score 8):

A time phrase in a present perfect construction cannot exclude the present and neither can it exclude the past.

**currently** excludes the past, and therefore cannot be used in combination with the present perfect.

> I have  worked currently at Google. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

That said, there are disjunct and elliptical constructions where a verb phrase such as **I am** might be understood.

> I've worked at Microsoft and Apple—and [I am] currently at Google.

Comment: However, a person who currently works at Google can accurately say "I have worked at Google" and optionally add "for five years" etc.  That he currently works at Google does not negate the present perfect description of the work he's already done there.

Thus, the combined statement of the three companies at which he's worked, with the qualifier for the current place of employ, is just fine.

However, the Oxford Comma following "Apple" is missing.
In contrast, unless he left the company and then returned later, he could not say "I *had* worked at Google"

Comment: @Monty Harder: you haven't used the word **currently** in your example.  The time phrase **for five years** does not exclude the past or the present. It is not the *fact* of his current employment status but the *time phrase(s)* used to describe it that is grammatical or ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2):

You would normally add a little more information around the currently.

Strictly speaking your wording would be okay in a conversation but sounds more natural if you are specific about what it is that you are "currently" doing.

So:

> "I have worked at Microsoft, Apple and currently Google"

Becomes:

> "I have worked at Microsoft, Apple and I am currently working at Google"

Also:

> "I have been a student in Paris, Rome, Madrid and currently London"

Becomes:

> "I have been a student in Paris, Rome, Madrid and I am currently studying in London"